# Check Raise vs Donk Bet

Tags: poker-theory

I am confused. What is the EV difference between a donk bet and a check raise? In which cases is it better to be donk betting and in which cases is it better to check raise?

Answer (score 3):

This is an important question. It's discussed on many sites and forums. I don't want to copy-paste the text as it would be my own, so:

[HERE](http://www.thepokerbank.com/strategy/plays/bet-or-check-raise/) you can find the summarized pros and cons of donkbet and check-raise.

And [HERE](http://www.dragthebar.com/poker-forums/showthread.php/6123-Check-Raising-vs-Donk-Betting-on-the-flop) are a good list of the situations when to use them.

To understand the second link, You must understand first polarization. You can find info [HERE](http://www.pokerjunkie.com/polarized-range-explained-poker-theory) about it.

Answer (score 1):

This really depends on many factors.

This is the thought process though:

```
-Fold equity difference between check raise & and donk bet.
-Line consistency with represented range(Do I want villain to call or fold? Which line best represents the range I want to represent for him to fold/for him to call?).
-Pot growth potential vs villain call frequency.
-What will I do if my donk bet gets raised?
```